# What would the implications of clams having legs have on the things that normally feed on them?

Tags: evolution

This question comes from [this BC comic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYXz0.jpg) where it's stated that they do. Also, how would people react if they discovered that fact?

Comment: Upvote in anticipation of you adding a square from  B.C to this question..  Quick, before this is put on hold for being lame.   CLAMS GOT LEGS!

Comment: Questions asking "How people would respond to x?" are often closed as too broad. People are so diverse and multifaceted that there is no simple answer to this question.

Comment: @sphennings the question about human response is tongue in cheek, but an animal that normally can't move (without great effort) gaining an extreme amount mobility (in this case, feet and legs) actually *is* serious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are very, very certain that clams lack legs. However, if somehow, we had missed major body parts to a creature we've been actually examining and even eating, it would be major news, as every single person who has worked/cooked with them would remember wrong.

People would be stunned, but many would not care. Some would claim it's a "Mandela Effect" most likely. Books and websites would be updated. That's pretty much it

Comment: ROFLMAO and the animals that hunt them?

Comment: @Jesse Cohoon They would have to mildly change their hunting strategies, if it were to effect them at all

Answer (score 2):

This is what we know about how clams feed,

> Clams typically draw in and expel water for respiration and feeding
>   through two tubes, the siphons, or “neck.” The water is impelled by
>   the beating of millions of cilia (hairlike structures) on the gills;
>   other gill cilia strain food from the incurrent water and transport
>   it, entangled in mucus, to the mouth.

Source: [Clams, Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/animal/clam)

While clams developing legs would be a wonderful piece of biological whimsy, since they belong to phylum Mollusca it is more likely they will develop a foot to move around on, just like a snail.

Considering the things they feed on are microscopic organisms floating or drifting in seawater, clams gaining mobility will not significantly affect their prey. Effectively nothing changes, except for the clams now getting around, which may improve their chances of finding currents carrying more microplankton for them to feed upon.

The main change for humans may be people saying "Catch that clam before it gets away."